# Adding current date to s3 table location

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I have a hive-script which export data from dynamo-db to s3.
I am trying to put the date to the location of dynamically created s3 folder.
Most probably i am in need of built in function of hive.
I searched web and found many examples of 
(String dt) -> and giving the date manually but I should input it automatically.

*Edit*
Should be something like that but I am having errors, that's my current hive script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracksTable (id bigint, json binary)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "tablename", 
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "id:id,json:json");


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s3( file Array<String> )
PARTITIONED BY ( dt STRING )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 's3://PATH'
WHERE dt = to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()));    

INSERT INTO TABLE S3
SELECT  func(json) FROM tracksTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed it like that ,

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE S3
    PARTITION(time)
    SELECT  func(json),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS time FROM tracksTable;
```